# Edit included PHP header to show CSS file specific to the page

Tags: php, css, include

So, I've had a look around, become somewhat overwhelmed by the variety of different answers I've come across and would like a hand.

My included PHP header CSS files currently look like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="CSS/header.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="CSS/ufc-blog.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="CSS/ufc205.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="CSS/cerrone-lawler.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

How can I specify the path and then enter a variable from the page with the included header that set the stylesheet to display the CSS specifically for that page?

Comment: As you allude to, there are many ways to do this.  What have you tried so far?  Some other things that are relevant to this decision are things like how many different css files are there?  Are you using some sort of cms (e.g. wordpress) or framework (e.g. symphony)?  Is the list of css files from a database or hard-coded for each page?

Comment: I've hand-coded the CSS, I just want a variable that is specified in the page that includes the php header file and write it to the href tag.

Comment: You may be interested in the `$_SERVER` superglobal. http://php.net/reserved.variables.server.  That includes a bunch a information about a given page that is being loaded.